# Initialize a boost::shared_ptr to NULL

Tags: c++, boost

Can I initialize `shared_ptr` with `NULL` value?

```
boost::shared_ptr<Type> s_obj(NULL);
```

If not, then how?

Comment: Isn't that what default construction does?

Comment: also nullptr makes more sense than NULL if C++11

Comment: If my `shared_ptr` already pointed to an object when I assigned it with a `NULL` (or `0`), is the ref count for the earlier object decremented?

Comment: As an aside, the reason this doesn't work is because NULL (or literal 0) goes through template deduction when trying to select the raw pointer constructor of boost::shared_ptr (which is a template). At this point, it is inferred to be a long, and long cannot be assigned to Type* (and no other constructor qualifies either).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The default construction does this for you:

```
template<class T> class shared_ptr
{
public:

    explicit shared_ptr(T * p = 0): px(p)
    { 
        //Snip
    }

    //...

private:

    T * px;            // contained pointer
    count_type * pn;   // ptr to reference counter
};
```

Answer (score 18):

That's the default construction, i.e.:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Type> s_obj;
```

`s_obj` now holds a null pointer and evaluates to boolean false when truth-tested;